# Why don't a singleton-shaped Thread-subclass instance's attributes of type Event return the same value?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have this part of code:

```
from threading import Thread, Event

class mySubThread(Thread):

    instance = []

    def __new__(cls):
        if not cls.instance:
            cls.instance.append(object.__new__(cls))
        return cls.instance[0]

    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = Event()
        self.exit = Event()
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while self.enabled.wait():
            if self.exit.is_set():
                break
            # ... boring useful stuff ...

    enable = lambda self: self.enabled.set()
    disable = lambda self: self.enabled.clear()

    def quit(self):
        self.enabled.set()
        self.exit.set()
```

When I set attributes which are instances of class `Event`, I get different values from their method `.is_set()` whether I take the attribute from `mySubThread()` or a name which is initialised as equal to it. And if I get the method from `mySubThread()`, then, from the named one, I see the value obtained is then equal to `mySubThread.attr.is_set()`. To make it more clear (even to me, what I wrote seems a bit confused), I have:

```
>>> named = mySubThread()
>>> named.enabled.is_set()
False
>>> named.enable()
>>> named.enabled.is_set()
True
>>> named is mySubThread()
True
>>> mySubThread().enabled.is_set()
False
>>> named.enabled.is_set()
False
```

While `mySubThread().enable()` sets `x.enabled.is_set()` to `True`, `mySubThread().enabled.is_set()` is always `False`.

Does anyone know if I did anything wrong, or is it a bug in Python?

I work on OS X.9.1 with Python 3.3.3 and GCC 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__init__` is called on the object returned from `__new__`. When you call `mySubThread()` the second time, your `__new__` returns a reference to the `named` object, and your `__init__` overwrites its attributes.